# GetSpecialFolder equivalent in golang

Tags: windows, go

I'm trying to get the temp folder of windows, other than a fixed path `C:\Windows\Temp`, I'd like to use some API similar to `GetSpecialFolder` in VBScript.

Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use [`os.TempDir()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#TempDir) for that.